# Missing Semicolon Error in node js webpack

Tags: node.js, json, webpack, babel-loader, eslintrc

I am getting semicolon error in one of my json files while building my project using webpack, my json files are formated and still giving me this error. I am using these
"@babel/cli": "^7.6.2",
"@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
"babel-core": "^6.26.3",
"babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
"babel-loader": "^9.1.0",
"eslint": "^7.0.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
"eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
"nodemon": "^2.0.20",
"nodemon-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.1",
"terser-webpack-plugin": "5.3.6",
"webpack": "^5.75.0",
"webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
"webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"

here is the error:

```
ERROR in ./src/express/routes/channels/libs/etsy/etsy.config.json
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\src\express\routes\channels\libs\etsy\etsy.config.json: Missing semicolon. (2:7)

  1 | {
> 2 |   "env": "development",
    |        ^
  3 |   "shopId": "FabricAndSewing",
  4 |   "key": "65hgx4sow7ih76bb9sir78f7",
  5 |   "secret": "8eoy84mw8u",
    at instantiate (C:\Excersys\FASAPI3\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:67:32)
    at constructor (C:\Excersys\FASAPI3\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:364:12)
```

webpackConfig.js

```
import * as path from "path";
import Dotenv from "dotenv-webpack";
import nodeExternals from "webpack-node-externals";
import NodemonPlugin from "nodemon-webpack-plugin";
const __dirname = path.resolve(path.dirname(""));

const config = (env, argv) => ({
  entry: {
    server: "./src/index.js",
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    publicPath: "/",
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  mode: argv.mode,
  target: "node",
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false,
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js/,
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false,
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
    parser: {
      javascript: {
        // ...
        commonjsMagicComments: true,
      },
    },
  },

  plugins: [new NodemonPlugin(), new Dotenv()],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".json", ".wasm"],
  },
});

export default config;
```

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
    es2022: true,
  },
  // extends: ['airbnb-base'],
  // globals: {
  //    Atomics: 'readonly',
  //    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly'
  //  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: "latest",
    sourceType: "module",
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
  },
  rules: {
    semi: "off",
  },
};
```

I tried different webpack and eslint configs but nothing worked

Comment: Has the file mistakenly been saved with/without a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)?

Comment: I hope the `shopId`, `key`, and `secret` you just shared in the error message are not important/production...

Comment: It looks like your code ends up trying to run a JSON file as JavaScript code. That won't work.

Comment: @tevemadar how to fix that

Comment: import config from './etsy.config.json';

Comment: thats how I am importing it

Comment: @SergeySosunov I don't understand what you are getting at sir.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I am not sure and don't know much about byte order mark

Comment: @tevemadar I used import config from "./etsy.config.json" assert { type: "json" };
 and still same error

Comment: and its a valid json file I validated it

Comment: @MTAC If you open the file in a hex editor, what are the values, in hex, of the first 3 bytes? N.B. it may not matter, but it is something to look for sometimes.